# "Independence" of surds

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I am pondering a question on field extensions, how do we show that $\sqrt[3] 2$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4] 5)$?

Intuitively it is "obvious" that no matter how we perform the usual operations it is not possible, but how do we show it rigorously?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like these, you may want to use the fact that if $M/L/K$ is a tower of field extensions, then $[M:L][L:K]=[M:K]$, where $[L:K]$ is the dimension of the $K$-vector space $L$ (with the scalar product given just be multiplication of elements in $L$ by elements in $K$).

At this point, one can show that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$.  If $\sqrt[3]{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$ and so we would get a tower of extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}$.  Thus, we should have that $3$ divides $4$, which doesn't happen, giving us a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[4] 5)$ is a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space with dimension $4$, while $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[3] 5)$ is a $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space with dimension $3$. As they're both field extensions, if the latter were contained in the former, its dimension should divide $4$.

Comment: Well, it is possible for a $3$-vector space to be subspace of a $4$-vector space. You need to say why. The real key is that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$ would be a vector space over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2)}$, and then the dimension becomes a problem...

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I thought about it very hard, but  'twas not enough, it seems  ;o). Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "between" argument, skipping field theory, but using linear algebra.

If $\sqrt[3]{2}\in\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$, then multiplication by $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a linear transformation, $T,$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. That linear transformation has a minimal polynomial, which is a factor of its four-dimensional characteristic polynomial.

The minimal polynomial is easily seen to be $x^3-2$ - if $p(T)=0$ then $x^3-2$ has to divide $p(x)$.

That means characteristic polynomial must be of the form $(x-a)(x^3-2)$, and have rational coefficients. Is that possible? This would mean that $a$ would have to be both a root of $x^3-2$ and rational. (The minimal polynomial of a linear transformation has to include all the roots of the characteristic polynomial.)